# PHP - Allow Users To Visit Only Once

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I'm looking to make a payment processing type script. Heres the steps.

Its for a Minecraft server so the players donate. Then paypal. Then gives the items.

1. The players enter their Minecraft in game names, it then creates a cookie for $player.
2. The player will click on the package they want, it will be directed to a PayPal package with a certain page redirect after payment. If the cookie is set, each different package will give different items and what not.
3. They then will have their items and be on their merry way :D

My issue is, if they are smart enough. They will go and abuse by refreshing and giving themselves items over and over by refreshing. What would be the best way of hiding that part of the process, or disallowing them to refresh the page and only allow one page visit?

Thanks,
Necro

Comment: The purpose of the site is you would post the relevant code here - not ask someone else to go to a chat room on another site to see it, that way others can come here and learn from your question

Comment: Sorry, I figured I might as well just direct them to the working code so they can wrap their head around it. Its not like I'm asking to fix any code...

Answer (score 4):

You should likely be using session variables to store this information, not cookies.  When the user has been redirected back to your site after payment processing on PayPal, you simply use the information you need from the session variable and then unset it so that it can't be used again.

Comment: You can use sessions to basically disable use of certain variables after the time has been up?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "after the time has been up".  I assume that when the user make a purchase, you are updating something in a database, or in another session variable that indicated when a user's privileges will expire.

Comment: When the user gets redirected, it will automatically trigger a command acting as the server on the minecraft server giving the items immediately. Or at least when they log into the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions can be circumvented either

1. using different browsers or
2. using a browser in a `VM`.

Logging the users `IP` one could limit access by IP to once every X days...

Another option is [BuyCraft](http://buycraft.net/). I use it myself and its really simple to setup + its a trusted plugin many users recognize.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried BuyCraft, I like it its rather easy your right, but I want to keep everything on my website and they have no API to integrate your website with the plugin so I figure this shouldn't be that hard. I don't think this will be that big of a deal if I just make sure I secure it as much as possible.

Comment: Understandable. It would be nice if they (Buycraft) had an API. Let me know how this turns out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not making use of the PayPal API via CURL and instead relying on PayPal redirecting to a non-indexed page of your website.

Use the PayPal API which will provide you with a 'token' and you can specify a return URL, when the user comes back to the return URL you can use the PayPal API to check that token is genuine. Disallowing someone from refreshing the page.

This would be a much better way to do a payment gateway.

Try something like this for reference:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/05/getting-started-with-the-paypal-api/